# How to set video/gif as background

Tags: video, background

How can I set video/gif as background banner and write text over it?

Comment: You need to create an `<image>` tag and a `<text>` tag. Use CSS styling to position and layer objects. For position you edit the `top` and `left` values, for layer order you edit the `z-index` value. Example: `<text id="myText" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2"> hello world </text>`.

Comment: PS: Let me know if it's doing what you want, then I can post as an Answer that you can accept.